# First order Peano axioms and their intepretation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I am still better trying to understand the first order Peano Axioms and their relation to the standard model. Just for reference, here are the axioms I work with:

$1.\space \forall x (\neg x+1=0)\hspace{2.14cm} 4.\space\forall x\forall y(x+1=y+1 \rightarrow x=y)\\
2.\space\forall x(x+0=x) \hspace{2.41cm} 5.\space\forall x\forall y(x+(y+1)=(x+y)+1)\\
3. \space \forall x(x\times0=0)\hspace{2.41cm} 6. \space \forall x\forall y (x\times(y+1) = (x\times y)+x)\\
 $

As well as the axiom schema of infinite, but countable axioms for induction:

$$7. \space\forall x_1...\forall x_n(\varphi[0/y]\land \forall y( \varphi\rightarrow \varphi[y+1/y]))\rightarrow \forall y\varphi)$$

Now, for correctness to hold, whatever is deduced from these axioms, must hold in every interpretation. But, what I find weird is, it seems these axioms have already defined the function symbols and constants to be equivalent to the structure of $\mathfrak N$, ie. $\{+,\times,0,1\}$, instead of having undefined $f_1,f_2,c_1,c_2$, so as I understand it the mappings are already assigned. How is this allowed, since clearly that's just one interpretation of the functions/constants, while the deduction should apply to every interpretation?

Further if that's the case, do the different possible models of PA concern themselves only with the domain $A$ of the model? I read that there are non-standard models of PA for every cardinality, so what would a model with cardinality of one look like?

Any examples/sources for FO Peano deductions are of course also welcome.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in axiom 1.

Comment: With regard to the "models of every cardinality," that's not true. There are models of every *infinite* cardinality, but PA has no finite models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, what I find weird is, it seems these axioms have already defined the function symbols and constants to be equivalent to the structure of $\mathfrak N$, ie. $\{+,\times,0,1\}$, instead of having undefined $f_1,f_2,c_1,c_2$, so as I understand it the mappings are already assigned.

No, they haven't.  The symbols $+$, $\times$, $0$, and $1$ used in the axioms are *just symbols*.  There is no assumption that they refer to the usual meaning of addition, multiplication, zero, and one: $+$ could be interpreted as any binary operation, $\times$ as any binary operation, and $0$ and $1$ as any two constants.  If you like, you could rewrite the axioms using $f_1,f_2,c_1,c_2$ as you suggest and the axioms would have the *exact same meaning*: you're just using different symbols.

> I read that there are non-standard models of PA for every cardinality, so what would a model with cardinality of one look like?

This statement is not quite correct.  There are non-standard models of PA of every *infinite* cardinality, but there are no finite models of PA.  For instance, you can prove from PA that the elements $0$, $1$, $1+1$, $(1+1)+1$, $((1+1)+1)+1$, and so on are all distinct, so there are infinitely many different elements.

Comment: So I take it that the arguably more common deductions (for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_addition_of_natural_numbers) in Peano Arithmetic use some other logic (would that count as 2nd order logic?). It seems a bit limiting to not be sure whether one is one :).

Comment: The arguments on that Wikipedia page do not assume that $+$, $\times$, $0$, and $1$ have their usual meanings either.  They do assume that $+$ has been defined recursively from a successor operation, which cannot be done in first-order logic and only makes sense in a second-order version of PA.  However, if you change these recursive definitions to axioms, then the arguments are perfectly valid in first-order logic.

Answer (score 0):

I thought [The Incompleteness Phenomenon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568810938)  by Goldstern and Judah captured this well, but there must be other books on the subject as well.  You have the Peano axioms and the standard model. A standard construction is to add a countable set of new axioms $c \gt 0, c \gt 1, c \gt 2, \ldots$  Any finite set of these axioms is satisfied by the standard model because you can find a greatest constant that $c$ must be greater than and choose it higher.  Compactness now tells you that all the axioms have a model, but the standard model does not satisfy it, so there must be a nonstandard model.  They state that all countable nonstandard models are of the form $\Bbb N$ followed by a dense linear order of sets isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$